# ipv6 multiple addresses and firewall on remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ipv6, ubuntu-12.04

I have an ubuntu server (serverA) which has a couple of IPv6 addresses. One of these is based on it's MAC address, and is known to the network, the other one I presume ubuntu created as a 'private' address which hides the MAC address.

I have another server (serverB) which hosts a database, and requires an incoming connection from serverA. serverB has a firewall, only allowing incoming connections from serverA. I've specified serverA's MAC-based IP address in serverB's firewall exceptions, but not knowing the private address, didn't add this in. However, packers from serverA seem to be defaulting to come from the private address.

Is the private address deterministic? How can I disable it? Should I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The privacy address is supposed to be random, and change often.  It shouldn't be deterministic; that would be antithetical to the concept.  It should be used for outgoing connections.

I don't recommend disabling it, because it is useful for not disclosing your MAC like the SLAAC (the proper term for the MAC-derived address) does.  However, some people who value the ability to determine which host made a connection later on prefer to disable it.

If you must use IP-based ACLs, you're going to have to disable it.  You can do so by adding `ip6-privacy=0` to the ipv6 section of `/etc/NetworkManager/system/connections/`.  You may also want to inspect `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf` if that doesn't put a stop to it.

Comment: You mention IP-based ACLs - are there any alternatives at the network/firewall level? Would a DNS-based firewall be any better in this case, as the private address is not static, hence not ideal for DNS? Are you suggesting dropping the firewall and relying on application-level security?

Comment: I find that there is only very rarely any reasonable use case for *egress* IP-based ACLs.  If you happen to have one, you probably can't use ipv6 privacy extensions is all.  You could certainly assign a static address that is not a SLAAC, though really this is no better than using the SLAAC from a security standpoint.

Comment: I don't care about the egress from serverA; it is the ingres ACL on serverB that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I will focus on your last question: *Should you disable private addresses?*

I agree with @Falcon that Privacy Extensions as defined in [RFC 4941](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941) are useful. I would always enable them on clients/workstations that may connect to services on the Internet, and I hope mobile phone producers will soon enable them per default on all their devices.

But in your setup, you are talking about two servers, where one of them is (not only, I assume) acting as a client to the other server. First questions would be: What is your setup? Are these servers within your company network? What external access will they have? Will `serverA` ever connect to the Internet (without a proxy)? If all traffic is internal and you do not see a threat by an adversary that maps your internal network traffic patterns, just disable Privacy Extensions on the servers. A server must by definition have at least one address that is well-known to its clients, mostly via DNS, so an attacker can use this address to attack the server. Hiding its address is not a valid attack mitigation strategy for a server. (Placing load balancers in front with its address is, of course.)

The **[US "DoD IPv6 Standard Profiles For IPv6 Capable Products"](http://jitc.fhu.disa.mil/apl/ipv6/pdf/disr_ipv6_50.pdf)** (sorry, I could not find a link to a version newer than 5.0) also demand Privacy Extensions for hosts/workstations "that will operate on networks requiring privacy address extensions or otherwise need to maintain anonymity" and strongly recommend them for other hosts/workstations. This requirement goes for servers **only if** they also act as clients (as in your setup) **and** need to maintain anonymity (which you must decide). So, the general server does not need Privacy Extensions activated.

Concerning the ACLs: If hard-coded IPv6 addresses must be used in several places, I would even consider defining fixed IPv6 addresses on your servers. You can set them on the servers and DNS or distribute them via DHCPv6, but you will have less work, compared to SLAAC addresses, if you ever have to replace a NIC or a server.

So, in short: *If your servers only communicate internally and do not have advanced security requirements against traffic analysis, you should disable Privacy Extensions. In any other case, you must balance your pros and cons.*

HTH.

Comment: Thanks; serverA will connect to the Internet occasionally. Both servers are virtual so movement isn't really a problem, but I think I'll move to a static, non-SLAAC address.

Answer (score 0):

Hello from 10 years later...

if serverA and serverB are in the same company's network (even if that is subdivided with firewalls), it could be possible to create "private" addresses in fd00::/8 network (or subnets thereof)

E.g., if serverA got additional address  fd00::a and  serverB got additional address fd00::b, and the routes are defined appropriately for fd00::/8, then serverA reaching serverB by that fd00-address will let it show up with its own static fd00-adress,   whereas any connections to the outside (e.g. google.com at 2a00:1450:4016:80b::200e) would then still use the non-constant private dynamic addresses.